# Showing every prime ideal is maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need help with this question number 8, at least some hints or approaches to start with. Sorry for posting an image, I am only doing so , because I don't have a pc to type the question in latex and I don't know how to do so using mobile in any other way. [image: the question]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a do-my-homework site.

Comment: Also, please remember to include the [source of the problems](https://www.isical.ac.in/~admission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/MMath-PMB-2017.pdf).

Comment: I am sorry but this isn't a homework, I am appearing in an exam and this is one of the 2018 exam paper questions. Should I send you the website link for clarification ?

Comment: https://www.isical.ac.in/~admission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/Questions-MMath.html

Comment: Here is the link of their previous year questions...and assumption is a weak argument.

Comment: @ravenchaser This is a highly duplicated question on the site. I found the suggested duplicate (out of a large cluster of duplicates) by searching "finite dimensional prime maximal."  Next time, please try something similar first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is an integral domain which is finite dimensional over some subfield

$k \subset D, \tag 1$

that is,

$\dim_k D = n < \infty, \tag 2$

then $D$ is in fact a field.  For given

$0 \ne u \in D, \tag 3$

the set of the first $n$ powers of $u$

$S = \{1_D, u, u^2, \ldots, u^n \} = \{ u^k, \; 0 \le k \le n, \; k \in \Bbb Z \} \subset D, \tag 4$

must contain a linearly dependent subset by virtue of (2); thus there exist

$\alpha_i \in k, \; 0 \le i \le n, \tag 5$

not all $0$, such that

$\displaystyle \sum_0^n \alpha_i u^i = 0; \tag 6$

thus we have

$p(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^n \alpha_i x^i \in k[x] \tag 7$

with

$p(u) = 0; \tag 8$

now granted that such polynomials exist, we may choose

$m(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg m} m_i x^i \in k[x], \; m(u) = 0, \tag 9$

of minimal degree amongst all such $p(x)$; for such $m(x)$,

$m_0 \ne 0 \tag{10}$

lest we write

$m(x) = x \displaystyle \sum_1^{\deg m} m_i x^{i - 1}, \tag{11}$

and hence

$u \displaystyle \sum_1^{\deg m} m_i u^{i - 1} = m(u) = 0, \tag{12}$

which since $u \ne 0$ implies

$\displaystyle \sum_1^{\deg m} m_i u^{i - 1} = 0, \tag{13}$

i.e., $u$ is a zero of

$g(x) = \displaystyle \sum_1^{\deg m} m_i x^{i - 1} \in k[x], \tag{14}$

which contradicts the mininality of the degree of $m(x)$ amongst polynomials satisfied by $u$; thus

$m_0 \ne 0, \tag{15}$

and we have

$\displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg m} m_i u^i = 0, \tag{16}$

or

$u\displaystyle \sum_1^{\deg m} m_i u^{i - 1} = \sum_1^{\deg m} m_i u^i = -m_0, \tag{17}$

whence

$u \left (-m_0^{-1} 
\displaystyle \sum_1^{\deg m} m_i u^{i - 1} \right ) = 1, \tag{18}$

that is,

$u^{-1} = -m_0^{-1} \displaystyle \sum_1^{\deg m} m_i u^{i - 1}; \tag{19}$

since every $0 \ne u \in D$ is invertible, we conclude that $D$ is a field; indeed, a field extension of $k$.

We apply this result to the present situation as follows:  if $P$ is prime in $D$, then $D/P$ is an integral domain, and (2) implies

$\dim_k D/P < \infty, \tag{20}$

as well; thus by what we have done above, $D/P$ is a field and hence $P$ is maximal in $D$. $OE\Delta$.

***Nota Bene:*** I must say in closing that if I were writing this proof as an answer to an exam (see comnents to the question itself), I would certainly find a way to make it shorter!  ***End of Note.***

Comment: Thank you for the nice proof. At point (6) can't we conclude u is an unit from there ? I mean, if we expand the summation, and use the fact, that the constant term isn't 0, then it's an unit being an element of K, and if the constant term was 0, then we can take " u" common and apply the same recursive process, eventually each coefficient will be a constant term and they can't be all zero since the combination is not linearly independent.

Comment: @ravenchaser:  well, by the time you've done what you suggested you've basically done what I did--the point is, you have to get to the minimal degree polynomial to ensure the constant term isn't zero.  If you wrote your proof out, it would I think be about as long as mine!  Anyway, thanks for the kind words and also for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Consider a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $R$. Observe that $R/\mathfrak p$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space. It is a consequence of the following result, which you can prove:

> Let $A\subset B$  be integral domains such that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module. Then $A$ is a field if and only if $B$ is a field.

*Edit*: You can adapt the proof of the left-to-right implication to your context. Here's how:

All you have to show is that any  non-zero element $\bar r\in R/\mathfrak p$ has a reciprocal. So consider multiplication by $\bar r$ in the quotient. Observe it is $k$-linear and injective. Furthermore $R/\mathfrak p$ is finite dimensional. What can you conclude from these elements?

Comment: I haven't studied modules since it was not in my bachelor's syllabus. Is there any other way that involve only ring theory and different integral domain chapters, including field extensions or linear algebra ,without the use of modules ? For example, can I somehow show this is an Principal ideal Domain since every prime ideal is maximal in it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, tere are plenty of examples where it isn't a P.I.D. You only need  $\rightarrow$ for your question. I'll add some more details in a moment.